# How to remove Scripts and Styles in content of SOLR Indexes[content field], while indexed through URL?

Tags: indexing, solrj, solr6

Whenever Solr is indexed to collection ( with configSet `sample_techproducts_configs`) and using URL,  via following command:

```
bin/post -p 8983 -c collection https://www.mywebsite.com -recursive 3
```

The indexes created do have a field `content` copied to `text` field.
This field do have value of the content of web page parsed using embedded tika parse. 
 
 
But, when those webpage contains any `<script>` or `<style>` tag the `<body>` is removed but the script or styles inside those respective tags remains as the content of the webpages, and shown in response to Solr Queries.

How To remove these unwanted content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do read the `inputstream` of *`DATA_MODE_WEB`* in `SimplePostTool` (only for whom the content type is "text/html" and remove all `<script>` and `<style>` tags with its content and again convert that content_String to stream using `stringToStream(String)` in `readPageFromUrl(URL u)` function.